# How to update files in a project and on other computers

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, maven, virtual-machine

I have several jar dependency files in my workspace. I would like to make it so these jars are updated with the most recent version in both my workspace and several virtual machine `nodes` that I have scattered about on the network.

For my workspace I believe I can use `Maven` to accomplish this, but I am not sure how I can make it so the files on my `nodes` are update along side the ones in my workspace.

Does anyone know of way for this to be done automatically?

Thanks for any hints.

**Side note:**
I'm asking as just a general question, but in case there needs to be more specifics let me know. I am working with selenium nodes and hubs.

Comment: Lots of options, from using systems like puppet to running maven on a cron schedule. I think this question is too broad for SO.

Comment: @KevinO I agree the question is too broad, kinda just wanted to see what options were out there for something like this as all my searches give me obscure articles. Do you recommend a good google search as I seem to be struggling with that XD

Comment: IMHO, there are too many variables. Should all the VMs be updated at the same time, or are some of these testing, quality, production? Do things need to be restarted after updating? Is there a change control system that needs to be respected? The list goes on. In general, maven is a dependency management tool, but it doesn't necessarily mean that the issue with the other nodes is one of dependency management. It could be a dev ops question, for example.

Comment: @KevinO I completely agree, I'll go ahead and close this, again I kinda just wanted a discussion on possibilities. I think the cron job approach is something I should follow for sure, thanks for the input!